# Issue with listbox1.items.add c#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I'm on a pathology project where in I have to display the name of doctor & patient name in listbox's single line providing space between them. The problem is that when the doctor's name is long enough it shifts the patient name to the right & left if it is small(vice-versa) which I don't want. I need them to be at the specific position.
Is there a way so that I can set the x and y coordinates for those text box values. I am using listbox1. I use the following command.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add("Dr."+textBox1.text+"              "+"Mrs."+textBox2.text);
```

and then I have to print it on A4 paper.

I know this is very simple, but I am new to C#. Please help.

Comment: how many spaces do you need to add between the text..? also are you familiar with the `new string(' ', 10);` overload for example instead of hitting the space bar you can initialize a new string variable to hold the pattern / token that you want for example if I want to show 5 `*` I would do var strPattern = new string('*', 5)` this will output 5 `*` please tell use the exact position if that does not work..then look up how to use `string.Format()` function

Comment: Hey! thanks for your reply, I need the patient name to appear at the right most edge of A4 paper & doctor's name to be at left edge of A4 paper.

Comment: This is a pathological case of using a ListBox when you really should be using a ListView with View = Details.

Comment: You mean i should be using ListView instead of Listbox ? Let me also tell you that I am adding the diagnostics tests (since its a pathology project) programatically to listbox. Is this possible in ListView ?

Comment: ...or a grid control.

Comment: Note that in a ListView you can only edit the 1st column. For better control I suggest to use two textboxes for data input..

Comment: Since you will also be printing the whole thing you need to be able to access the two string items separately. So a ListView is a good container. Just keep in mind that you can't really print it. Printing is a completely separate issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a datatemplate for your listbboxitems.

Within your datatemplate create two controls that sit next to each other (one for Dr and another one for patient).

**Example:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lbDatabases" Height="138" Width="498" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="146"  >
    <ListView.View >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <stackpanel Orientation=Horizontal>
                        <TextBlock />
                        <TextBlock />
                      </stackpanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView.View> </ListView>
```

Comment: Well given that this is a UI specific issue, what UI framework is being used?

Comment: Hi, as I said earlier, I am new to C#.Net. The only thing I can answer here is that I am using Visual Studio 2005 with .NetFramework 3.5.

Comment: @ashishkumar when you are building the form, is there a section that looks like the code scott posted above, or is there just a display of what the window will look like?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can recommend to do this would be to use a fixed-width font that is the same character width for all of its characters.  Then, you can count characters and measure out the names appropriately.  Extremely long names may break your system though.

In a professional application, I would not do this.  Just FYI.

Fixed width fonts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

And here is the code (console is fixed-width):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string doctorName = "Dr. Vee";
        string patientName = "Mrs. Park";

        string doctorName2 = "Dr. Longer";
        string patientName2 = "Mr. Ranker";


        Console.WriteLine(GetFinalString(doctorName, patientName));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFinalString(doctorName2, patientName2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetFinalString(string doctorName, string patientName)
    {
        int targetPatientLocation = 15;
        int length = doctorName.ToCharArray().Count();
        int targetPatientSpaces = targetPatientLocation - length;

        string final = doctorName;
        for (int i = 0; i < targetPatientSpaces; i++)
        {
            final += " ";
        }
        final += patientName;
        return final;
    }
```

This produces the strings you would be looking for, but again I wouldn't do this since it only takes a long doctor name to break this logic.